# Function Prototyping, Program Pause

Tags: c++, function, prototype

Here is a program with a function prototype.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print(string name);

int main(void)
{
   string user;
   cout << "Hello, what's your name?";
   cout << "Name: ";
   print(user);
   return(0);
}

void print(string name)
{
   cout << "Hello " << name << " my dear friend! :) \n";
}
```

I understand that function prototyping is a way of alerting the compiler that (in our case), `void print(string name)` is somewhere within the program. Since the computer "reads" left to right, top to bottom, is it possible (or more correctly, logical) that the program "pauses" as the copmuter searches for the function during execution?

Comment: Function calls (those not called through function pointers) are resolved at compile time. C++ is not an interpreted language.

Comment: In this case it is not just a function prototype, but it is a forward declaration.

Answer (score 3):

> Since the computer "reads" left to right, top to bottom, is it possible (or more correctly, logical) that the program "pauses" as the copmuter searches for the function during execution?

The call to `print` in `main` (and any other functions that may call the function) is resolved at link time. There is no searching required at execution time.